# Problems with limits of categorical axis in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am having problems with the limits on my categorical x-axis. Here's my data frame `sub1`:

```
structure(list(YR = structure(1:83, .Label = c("1886", "1888", 
"1890", "1899", "1903", "1923", "1930", "1935", "1936", "1938", 
"1939", "1940", "1942", "1943", "1946", "1947", "1948", "1949", 
"1950", "1952", "1953", "1954", "1955", "1956", "1957", "1959", 
"1960", "1961", "1962", "1963", "1964", "1965", "1966", "1967", 
"1968", "1969", "1970", "1971", "1972", "1973", "1974", "1975", 
"1976", "1977", "1978", "1979", "1980", "1981", "1982", "1983", 
"1984", "1985", "1986", "1987", "1988", "1989", "1990", "1991", 
"1992", "1993", "1994", "1995", "1996", "1997", "1998", "1999", 
"2000", "2001", "2002", "2003", "2004", "2005", "2006", "2007", 
"2008", "2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", 
"2016"), class = "factor"), Freq = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 4L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 4L)), .Names = c("YR", 
"Freq"), row.names = 84:166, class = "data.frame")
```

And here's the plot script:

```
ggplot(sub1, aes(x=YR,y=Freq)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(limit=c(0,8),expand=c(0, 0)) +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks=c("1965","1970","1975","1980",
                            "1985","1990","1995","2000",
                            "2005","2010","2015")) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
  xlab("") + ylab("No of papers")
```

And here's the plot:

[image]

Then, when I add a few more x-axis breaks:

```
ggplot(sub1, aes(x=YR,y=Freq)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(limit=c(0,8),expand=c(0, 0)) +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks=c("1920","1925","1930","1935","1940","1945",
                            "1950","1955","1960","1965","1970","1975",
                            "1980","1985","1990","1995","2000",
                            "2005","2010","2015")) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
  xlab("") + ylab("No of papers")
```

something peculiar happens with the x-axis:

[image]

Where's the bug?

Comment: Are you trying to change the limits of your plot as well as the breaks?  If so, you could subset the dataset to the years you want to plot or use the `limits` argument (i.e., `limits = as.character(1965:2015)`).

Comment: This command does not get rid of the "open" area on the axis, but moves it to the right of the labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your YR factor is missing years. R doesn't know these are years, just a list of factors.

Include this code before you run `ggplot`:

```
sub1 <- merge(data.frame(YR=1886:2016), sub1, all.x = TRUE)
sub1$YR <- as.factor(sub1$YR)
sub1[is.na(sub1)] <- 0
```

Comment: Adding this code still doesn't fix the problem, all labels (1960-2015) and bars are still on the right side of the chart.

Comment: That's a separate problem from your years not spacing evenly. You may want to switch from storing YR as factors to an integer or a year. Then the usual limit operations work in ggplot.